# What physical and medical problems do wild horse twins suffer from?

Tags: biology, fauna, medical, horses

Twin foals are uncommon and undesirable, or so I read. They have retarded growth and developmental problems, and require additional care. (Assuming they survive to term, which they may well not.)

The articles I am reading are written from the perspective of domesticated horses, in which vets will intervene, and human carers will encourage the foals to live quietly so that they can develop somewhat before becoming independent.

My story will feature wild horse twins. Let's assume they survive the birth but do not have human intervention to help them grow and develop.

What (possibly life-threatening, but not actually lethal) problems will these creatures likely suffer from?

Comment: I'm confused as to the worldbuilding problem you're facing. This forum, as I'm sure you're aware, is the making of fictional worlds & settings. I don't see any fictional world context in your question that couldn't be better answered by a large animal veterinarian forum. VTC.

Answer (score 3):

**Calcium deficiency around birth.**

The extra demands on the mother to supply nutrients to the two in pregnancy has lead to soft bones at birth. Since one of the things foals need to do almost immediately on being thrust into the world is get-up and follow mother, suckling when allowed - they must of necessity walk.

The strain on the bones, rubbery through lack of calcium phosphate meant that the legs were not quite rigid enough to stay straight. One's forelegs becoming bandy ([valgus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varus_deformity)) the other perhaps bowed (varus).

[image]

<sup>Image ironwillvets.com 2021</sup>

In captivity this would easily be corrected with a soft brace, or in more severe cases, surgery. But left unchecked could result in a fall in later life, a break, immobility and death through exposure or being set-upon by predators or scavengers.

**Asthma and allergies.**

Another known issue is sensitive lungs. Perhaps they're fine in dry air with little pollen, but when the Mountain Oak forests start producing pollen, they  get very short of breath, tightness in the chest and neck muscles, feelings of panic or "impending doom", uncontrollable coughing, life-threatening if it goes too far - best to stay away from those forests (and avoid being down-wind of them).

In extremis, an emergency relief from the symptoms would be to ingest a tea made from the plant [Ephedra sinica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephedra_sinica), or the plant itself directly as it contains the chemicals [ephedrine and pseudo-ephedrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephedra), which act to dilate the breathing tubes and relieve symptoms, maybe enough to save life - if it can be found in-time.